# Print in Visual Studio Using an Avery template

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I am using Visual Studio 2010 to pull inventory information from a SQL database. We are trying to print this information on labels to affix to bins and parts. I am trying to utilize an Avery style sheet to print the labels on a normal Lexmark printer. I have never done this in Visual Studio and have no idea where to start. The style is 80102. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: more relevant than the style is your programming language. which is it?

Comment: I believe that it is C#.

Comment: what if you use word? you can generate a web service in .net or use recorset.save method in clasic asp, any two acting as source for word's "merge mail" feature.

Comment: Yes, we can do that, but we are trying to set this up for people to do themselves, and they are not that tech savvy. We want this set up so when they export the result set to a PDF, they can hit print and it lines up perfectly and prints.